# How can I get accurate value of temperature and humidity from DHT11 and ESP8266

Tags: arduino-esp8266

I would like to measure the temperature and humidity from DHT11 sensor and ESP8266.
To do so, I made some code by using two libraries.

But none of these can give me an accurate number of humidity and temperature value.
All I can get an output are like followings.

Temperature = 21.0000
Humidity = 48.0000
[image]

Please give me a hint to upgrade my code.

First code

```
#include <DHTesp.h>

DHTesp dht;

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(0, INPUT);
  dht.setup(0, DHTesp::DHT11);
}
void loop(){
  Serial.print("Temperature = ");
  Serial.println(dht.getTemperature(), 4);
  Serial.print("Humidity = ");
  Serial.println(dht.getHumidity(), 4);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Seconde code

```
#include <DHT.h>
DHT dht(0, DHT11);


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(0, INPUT);
  dht.begin();
}

void loop() {
 
    float humidity = dht.readHumidity();
    float temp = dht.readTemperature();
    delay(500);
    Serial.println(humidity);

}
```

Comment: What I want to get is float return value for temperature and humidity.

Comment: The value of temperature and humidity are 21.0000 and 48.0000. It looks like float but these values are integer I think.

Comment: How you come to the conclusion they are integers? Looks all good to me, especially second code. I am using similar approach in my projects too.

Comment: I think it is very weird.
I added a picture.

Answer (score 2):

From DHT11 [datasheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/758/DHT11-Technical-Data-Sheet-Translated-Version-1143054.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjutYT49pTsAhUlpXIEHaS3AsoQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw2tdFgaeZgeQmJr3SkJiugP), it only supports resolution to 1 degree Celsius and 8bits for humidity leading to the integer like floats.

Also something to keep in mind is the units that the DHT11 and DHT22 output.

Temperature is returned as Celsius and humidity is a value between 0 - 100 representing the relative humidity.

To convert between Celsius and Fahrenheit, you can use this formula

`Serial.print((int)round(1.8*temp+32));`

Comment: But I really want to know is why DHT11 unit returns only integer like value.

Comment: I believe, without going too deep into the datasheets, that DHT11 only supports integral resolution for temperature. DHT22 should provide float values.

Comment: Confirmed to be accurate to nearest degree Celsius

Comment: Yes, @AlanCheung is right. You are not getting integers as a result, you are getting floats, but resolution of DHT11 is 1 degree. All DHT libraries are supporting multiple sensor types so they are using floats to be able to support higher resolutions.

Comment: Thank you Alan and Zoran. I checked these comments just before.